# boost::ifind_first with std::string objects

Tags: c++, algorithm, string, boost

I am trying to use boost string algorithms for case insensitive search.
total newbie here.

if I am using it this way, I get an error.

```
std::string str1("Hello world");
std::string str2("hello");
if ( boost::ifind_first(str1, str2) ) some code;
```

Converting to char pointers resolves the problem.

```
boost::ifind_first( (char*)str1.c_str(), (char*)str2.c_str() );
```

Is there a way to search std::string objects directly?

Also, maybe there is another way to know if string is present inside another string with case-insensitive search?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use boost::iterator_range.  This works:

```
  typedef const boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator> StringRange;
  std::string str1("Hello world");
  std::string str2("hello");

  if ( boost::ifind_first(
          StringRange(str1.begin(), str1.end()),
          StringRange(str2.begin(), str2.end()) ) )
      std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
```

EDIT: Using a const iterator_range in the typedef allows passing a temporary range.

Comment: The first argument of ifind_first() is Range1T&. It is not standard to pass a temporary range.

Comment: @DanielLaügt: `Range1T` will be deduced to be `const boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator>`, resulting in a const reference. You have a problem with passing a const reference to a temporary?

Comment: I have not seen the const before iterator_range. This works fine. I didn't know that we can do this kind of trick. I've learn something. Thanks.

Comment: However this doesn't compile on msvc with /Za option. Probably a bug in microsoft compiler as it compiles fine on gcc and clang...

Comment: I get a error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::_String_const_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'std::_String_iterator<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' with this code in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

The more simplicity way

```cpp
std::string str1("Hello world");
std::string str2("hello");
if (boost::icontains(str1, str2)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do a case-insensitive comparison of strings without modifying either string.

```
int nocase_cmp(const string & s1, const string& s2) 
{
  string::const_iterator it1=s1.begin();
  string::const_iterator it2=s2.begin();

  //stop when either string's end has been reached
  while ( (it1!=s1.end()) && (it2!=s2.end()) ) 
  { 
    if(::toupper(*it1) != ::toupper(*it2)) //letters differ?
     // return -1 to indicate smaller than, 1 otherwise
     return (::toupper(*it1)  < ::toupper(*it2)) ? -1 : 1; 
    //proceed to the next character in each string
    ++it1;
    ++it2;
  }
  size_t size1=s1.size(), size2=s2.size();// cache lengths
  //return -1,0 or 1 according to strings' lengths
  if (size1==size2)  {
    return 0;
  }
  return (size1<size2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(char*)str.c_str()` is actually performing a `const_cast`: `const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())`. I very seriously doubt that it is necessary to cast away `const` in order to search through the string.

I have never used `boost::ifind_first`, but according to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/ifind_first.html), the function takes two ranges. I suppose there's a way to create a range from a string? OTOH, I'd wonder if a string wasn't a perfect range.

It might be helpful if you post the full error messages of the compiler you used.